# undefined method `total' for nil:NilClass NoMethodError in ReservationsController#checkout

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, braintree

Im currently stuck unable to figure out how to get params from one controller to add to the next controller. Iv tried `render` and `redirect_to` and I still cant get this to work!!

Heres my controller and view
- form in view gets the action of my `checkout controller`
-I want to use the same reservation.id in both checkout and create controllers, so I can call reservation.total in the checkout controller.

How can I get the total on create controller to hope over and share on the checkout controller??

Error Log:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `total' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/reservations_controller.rb:45:in `checkout'
```

reservations controller:

```rails
def checkout




nonce = params[:payment_method_nonce]
 result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
  :amount => @reservation.total,
  :payment_method_nonce => nonce,
  :options => {
    :submit_for_settlement => true
  }
)
 if result.success?
  puts "success!: #{result.transaction.id}"
elsif result.transaction
  puts "Error processing transaction:"
  puts "code: #{result.transaction.processor_response_code}"
  puts "text: #{result.transaction.processor_response_text}"
else
  p result.errors
end


end



def create

#!/usr/bin/env ruby


    reviser = Reviser.find(params[:reviser_id])
        @reservation = current_user.reservations.create(reservation_params)

        if @reservation.total > 0

            @token = Braintree::ClientToken.generate


        elsif @reservation.total == 0
            @reservation.update_attributes status: true
            redirect_to @reservation.reviser.user, alert: "Writing Request Success"


        else
            redirect_to @reservation.reviser, alert: "Oops, something went wrong..."
        end 




    end
```

create html:

```html
<p>create</p>


<form id="checkout" method="post" action="/checkout">
  <div id="payment-form"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Pay">
</form>

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.26.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
// We generated a client token for you so you can test out this code
// immediately. In a production-ready integration, you will need to
// generate a client token on your server (see section below).
// var clientToken = "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";



var clientToken = "<%= @token %>";

braintree.setup(clientToken, "dropin", {
  container: "payment-form"
});
</script>
```

```
post 'checkout', to: 'reservations#checkout'
get 'checkout', to: 'reservations#checkout'
```

Comment: Can't you just do find reservation by params :id? in checkout controller?

Comment: You are also missing @ in @reviser in def create

Comment: @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id]) gives me a different error: Couldn't find Reservation with 'id'=

Comment: Might want to look into using Ajax / respond_to in Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to make the checkout method as a member method i.e pass the id of the reservation in the url.

```
post 'checkout/:id', to: 'reservations#checkout', :as => 'reservation_checkout'
```

By doing this you will be able to find the reservation like.

```
@reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id]) #so you will not get the error undefined method `total' for nil:NilClass
```

I am wondering why don't you use html.erb

```
<%= form_tag reservation_checkout_path(@reservation) %>
  #your fields
<% end %>
```

Comment: i tried the form tag and it seemed to go through with `post 'reservations/checkout', to: 'reservations#checkout'` however the id still wouldnt get solved. I tried the others and they arent working either. i get Couldn't find Reservation with 'id'=......when i use the checkout/:id...When I do the reservation_checkout_path one the url has the id after checkout. like this: http://localhost:3000/reservations/checkout.338

Comment: I am thinking that you first need to go through with the rails guide tutorial http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-rails-project that will definitely clear concepts about routing and all. hope that help!